# How do I implement the c# setmodifiedflag syntax

Tags: c#

I have made a simple editor for text files.
and I want to add the feature:
If closing the unsaved file I want a warning.

how do I use the setmodifiedflag.

My code is:

```
 private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
           saveFileDialog1.Filter= "Ticker Files,*.tic, *.csv|*.tic;*.csv;";
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                try
                {

                    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, richTextBox1.Text);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

                }
        }

        private void True(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
          (here I will call the setmodified flag, how to?)
        }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: True is a terrible name for any function particularly for a handler function. I assume you are handling a user key stroke inside the document. You should probably cast the sender to CDocument and call the function, something like:   `if(sender is CDocument)   {  (sender as CDocument).SetModifiedFlag();  } `   Bear in mind that this doesn't deal with undo that reverts the file to its clean state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am quite new in the c# language so if you have the time to guide me about this topic, codes, tutorials it will be very helpfull. How do I implement your code into my app. kind regards Kurt K

Comment: Well, have you tried adding my piece of code where you have your comment? It's quite possible that sender isn't a CDocument but rather a control within the document, you can check to see what sender is with the debugger by adding a breakpoint on that line. If it's a control within the document, it's probably possible to get its containing document somehow or you can always keep a reference to your current document in the editor.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have solved the problem in another way. richtextbox1 textchanged , and then using form1 formClosed.  kind regards